# Database schema for a products and bugs aggregator

Tags: sql, database

As an exercise in learning, I'm creating a bugs/issues tracking and "aggregator" web application. A simple app consisting of products, issues, reviews and links related to it. The links will be urls pointing to issues/reviews already created on external sites (bugzillas, stackoverflow, etc). Here is my initial effort towards creating the database schema of the app:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255), --Samsung Galaxy, Apple iphone, Dell Inspiron, GNOME Desktop, etc.
    VERSION VARCHAR(255), --S5, v3.14, etc.
    IMAGE VARCHAR(255), --PATH TO UPLOADED IMAGE FILE
    CATEGORIES VARCHAR(255),
    TAGS VARCHAR(255),
    CREATOR VARCHAR(255) --EMAIL ADDRESS OF PRODUCT UPLOADER
);

CREATE TABLE REVIEWS (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    PRODUCT_ID INTEGER,
    CREATOR VARCHAR(255), --EMAIL ADD. OF REVIEWER
);

CREATE TABLE ISSUES(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    PRODUCT_ID INTE GER,
    CREATOR VARCHAR(255), --EMAIL ADDRESS
    DESCN VARCHAR(255), --DESCRIPTION
    LINKS VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE LINKS(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    PRODUCT_ID INTEGER,
    LINK_TYPE VARCHAR(255), --ISSUE OR REVIEW OR OTHER (STACKOVERFLOW/REDDIT/HN CONTENT)
    DESCN VARCHAR(255), --A SHORT PREVIEW OF LINKED CONTENT
    URL VARCHAR(255),
    LAST_UPDATED DATETIME, --CRAWLER TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_VOTES(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LINK_ID INTEGER,
    VOTER VARCHAR(255), --EMAIL ADD. OF THE VOTER
    VOTE INTEGER, --1==UP, 0==DOWN
);
```

Appreciate if you can provide me suggestions, improvements, etc.

Comment: Is this for [tag:mysql]? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: @200_success Yes. Though my original idea is database agnostic, this particular prototype implementation is in `mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CATEGORIES VARCHAR(255),
TAGS VARCHAR(255),
```

Take care with plural named fields. It's very, very likely that any plural field is secretly a multi-valued field. You might want to extract a "Category" and "Tag" table out of this, so searching for them is easier.

```
PRODUCT_ID INTE GER,
```

You've got a space there. Not sure if SQL is okay with that.

Lastly, I think you should put some `NOT NULL` in there - are you sure every field except the primaries can be NULL? You also seem to be missing foreign keys from one table to another.